# Can an indemnification clause be satisfied by personally representing the company if the user is an attorney?

Tags: united-states

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83026/can-i-be-forced-to-indemnify-a-company-for-my-own-claims) about indemnification clauses in ToSes made me wonder what happens if the user is an attorney. The [Tower of Fantasy ToS](https://www.toweroffantasy-global.com/UserAgreement.html) (using that example because it was used in the original question) says "If someone sues us based on your breach of this EULA or your access or use of the Services, you agree to defend us or pay for our defense in that lawsuit." If the user is an attorney, can (s)he satisfy this requirement by personally representing the company without charging them, or could the company require him/her to pay for another attorney of their choice?

Comment: Interesting question. Not convinced it has a clear and predictable answer, or that there is controlling law on point in most jurisdictions.

Comment: Note, the line you quoted isn't actually part of the EULA. It's italicized, and as per section 2 of the EULA, "You’ll notice that we added some text in italics throughout the EULA to make it easier to read; however, this text is provided for guidance only, and does not form part of the EULA."

Comment: The actual EULA text is pretty explicit about having to pay.

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer, but there could be a perception of a conflict of interest. If you are willing to engage in conduct that gets the company sued, you might be tempted to not give the defense your all and allow them to lose.